# To paste cell range from Excel to Powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, paste, vba

I have this one presentation slides which already has its content. My goal now is to paste new things from Excel to the same slides, instead of adding new slides to the PowerPoint file. The language I'm using is VBA.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreatePowerPoint()
'-------------------------------------------
'ADD A REFERENCE TO THE MICROSOFT POWERPOINT LIBRARY BY:
     '1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
     '2. Click on Reference
     '3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay
'-------------------------------------------
'FIRST WE DECLARE THE VARIABLES WE WILL BE USING
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    'Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range, row As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    row = 1
'-------------------------------------------
'LOOK FOR EXISTING INSTANCE
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
'-------------------------------------------
'LET'S CREATE A NEW POWERPOINT
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
'-------------------------------------------
'MAKE A PRESENTATION IN POWERPOINT
    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If
'-------------------------------------------
'SHOW THE POWERPOINT
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True
'-------------------------------------------
'LOOP THROUGH EACH RANGE DATA SET IN THE EXCEL WORKBOOK AND PASTE THEM INTO THE POWERPOINT
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         'For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
         LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
         Do Until row >= LastRow
            For I = row To LastRow
                If Cells(I, 1) = "|" Then
                    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Set rng = Range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(I - 1, LastCol))

'Note: xlUp, xlToLeft = Returns a Range object that represents the cell at the end of the region that contains the source range.
'Equivalent to pressing END+UP ARROW, END+DOWN ARROW, END+LEFT ARROW, or END+RIGHT ARROW. Read-only Range object.
'-------------------------------------------
'ADD A NEW SLIDE WHERE WE WILL PASTE THE TABLE
                    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
                    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
                    Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
'Note: ppLayoutText = the layout of the slide
'-------------------------------------------
'COPY THE TABLE AND PASTE IT INTO THE POWERPOINT AS DEFAULT (EDITABLE FORM IN PPT)
                    'tbl.Range.Copy
                    rng.Copy
                    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
'Note:ppPasteEnhancedMetafile/ppPasteOLEObject = if want to edit in Excel form
'-------------------------------------------
'ADJUST THE POSITIONING OF THE TABLE ON POWERPOINT SLIDE
                    With newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
                        .Left = 20
                        .Top = 125
                        .Width = 675
                    End With
                    activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
                    activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 505
                    row = I
                    Exit For
                End If
         'Next tbl
            Next I
            row = row + 1
        Loop

    Next sht
'-------------------------------------------
'CLEANUP
     Set activeSlide = Nothing
     Set newPowerPoint = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Instead of adding new slides, I would like to paste it inside an active PowerPoint slides which already has some content in it. May anyone assist me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly reference the slide.  I would explicitly reference the presentation too.
the slides(1) is referencing slide number 1.

```
'COPY THE TABLE AND PASTE IT INTO THE POWERPOINT AS DEFAULT (EDITABLE FORM IN PPT)
                    'tbl.Range.Copy
                    rng.Copy
                    Presentation ("PPT file name.pptx").Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
```

Comment: Hi Mooseman, the issue is specific table has to be pasted to specific slide. How can I reference specific table to specific slide? Is there any way?

Comment: Well, I just showed you how to define a specific slide, you just have to define a specific table.  Workbook("Excel file name".Sheets("sheet name or index number).table('table name").copy  Something like that.